# Lua - How to analyse a .csv export to show the highest, lowest and average values etc

Tags: csv, lua

Using Lua, i’m downloading a .csv file and then taking the first line and last line to help me validate the time period visually by the start and end date/times provided.

I’d also like to scan through the values and create a variety of variables e.g the highest, lowest and average value reported during that period.

The .csv is formatted in the following way..

```
created_at,entry_id,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8
2021-04-16 20:18:11 UTC,6097,17.5,21.1,20,20,19.5,16.1,6.7,15.10
2021-04-16 20:48:11 UTC,6098,17.5,21.1,20,20,19.5,16.3,6.1,14.30
2021-04-16 21:18:11 UTC,6099,17.5,21.1,20,20,19.6,17.2,5.5,14.30
2021-04-16 21:48:11 UTC,6100,17.5,21,20,20,19.4,17.9,4.9,13.40
2021-04-16 22:18:11 UTC,6101,17.5,20.8,20,20,19.1,18.5,4.4,13.40
2021-04-16 22:48:11 UTC,6102,17.5,20.6,20,20,18.7,18.9,3.9,12.40
2021-04-16 23:18:11 UTC,6103,17.5,20.4,19.5,20,18.4,19.2,3.5,12.40
```

And my code to get the first and last line is as follows

```
print("Part 1")
print("Start : check 2nd and last row of csv")
local ctr = 0
local i = 0
local csvfilename = "/home/pi/shared/feed12hr.csv"
local hFile = io.open(csvfilename, "r")
    for _ in io.lines(csvfilename) do ctr = ctr + 1 end
    print("......  Count : Number of lines downloaded = " ..ctr)

local linenumbera = 2
local linenumberb = ctr
    for line in io.lines(csvfilename) do i = i + 1
        if i == linenumbera then 
            secondline = line
            print("......  2nd Line is = " ..secondline) end
        if i == linenumberb then 
            lastline = line
            print("......  Last line is = " ..lastline)
     -- return line
  end
end
print("End : Extracted 2nd and last row of csv")
```

But I now plan to pick a column, ideally by name (as I’d like to be able to use this against other .csv exports that are of a similar structure.) And get the .csv into a table/array...

I’ve found an option for that here - [Csv file to a Lua table and access the lines as new table or function()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587196/csv-file-to-a-lua-table-and-access-the-lines-as-new-table-or-function)

See below..

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

print("Part 2") 
print("Start : Convert .csv to table")

local csvfilename = "/home/pi/shared/feed12hr.csv"
local csv = io.open(csvfilename, "r")

local items = {}                      -- Store our values here
local headers = {}                    -- 
local first = true
for line in csv:gmatch("[^\n]+") do
  if first then                       -- this is to handle the first line and capture our headers.
    local count = 1
    for header in line:gmatch("[^,]+") do 
      headers[count] = header
      count = count + 1
    end
    first = false                     -- set first to false to switch off the header block
  else
    local name
    local i = 2                       -- We start at 2 because we wont be increment for the header
    for field in line:gmatch("[^,]+") do
      name = name or field            -- check if we know the name of our row
      if items[name] then             -- if the name is already in the items table then this is a field
        items[name][headers[i]] = field -- assign our value at the header in the table with the given name.
        i = i + 1
      else                            -- if the name is not in the table we create a new index for it
        items[name] = {}
      end
    end
  end
end

print("End : .csv now in table/array structure")
```

But I’m getting the following error ??

```
pi@raspberrypi:/ $ lua home/pi/Documents/csv_to_table.lua
Part 2
Start : Convert .csv to table
lua: home/pi/Documents/csv_to_table.lua:12: attempt to call method 'gmatch' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        home/pi/Documents/csv_to_table.lua:12: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
pi@raspberrypi:/ $
```

Any ideas on that ?
I can confirm that the .csv file is there ?

Once everything (hopefully) is in a table - I then want to be able to generate a list of variables based on the information in a chosen column, which I can then use and send within a push notification or email (which I already have the code for).

The following is what I’ve been able to create so far, but I would appreciate any/all help to do more analysis of the values within the chosen  column so I can see all things like get highest, lowest, average etc.

```
print("Part 3") 
print("Start : Create .csv analysis values/variables")

local total = 0 
local count = 0
for name, item in pairs(items) do
  for field, value in pairs(item) do
      if field == "cabin" then
    print(field .. " = ".. value)
    total = total + value
    count = count + 1
  end
end
end

local average = tonumber(total/count)
local roundupdown = math.floor(average * 100)/100
print(count)
print(total)
print(total/count)
print(rounddown)

print("End : analysis values/variables created")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

io.open returns a file handle on success. Not a string.

Hence

```
local csv = io.open(csvfilename, "r")
--...
  for line in csv:gmatch("[^\n]+") do
--...
```

will raise an error.

You need to read the file into a string first.

Alternatively can iterate over the lines of a file using `file:lines(...)` or `io.lines` as you already do in your code.

```
local csv = io.open(csvfilename, "r")
if csv then
  for line in csv:lines() do
-- ...
```

You're iterating over the file more often than you need to.

#### Edit:

This is how you could fill a data table while calculating the maxima for each row on the fly. This assumes you always have valid lines! A proper solution should verify the data.

```
-- prepare a table to store the minima and maxima in
local colExtrema = {min = {}, max = {}}
local rows = {}
-- go over the file linewise
for line in csvFile:lines() do
  -- split the line into 3 parts
  local timeStamp, id, dataStr = line:match("([^,]+),(%d+),(.*)")
  -- create a row container
  local row = {timeStamp = timeStamp, id = id, data = {}}
  -- fill the row data
  for val in dataStr:gmatch("[%d%.]+") do
    table.insert(row.data, val)
    -- find the biggest value so far
    -- our initial value is the smallest number possible
    local oldMax = colExtrema[#row.data].max or -math.huge
    -- store the bigger value as the new maximum
    colExtrema.max[#row.data] = math.max(val, oldMax)
  end
  -- insert row data
  table.insert(rows, row)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Piglet, can’t believe I missed that - sorry, but thanks for the reminder - `local content = csv:read("*all")
csv:close()` Now the main goal of the post was to find the key values within that column, such as the highest, lowest, average, most frequent etc. - how do I do that ? I really want to build out that ‘Part 3’ section ..

Comment: Hi @piglet, and further thoughts on how to create a variable for the highest, lowest vales in the chosen column ?

Comment: not sure what you need to know. you run over that file getting 1 line each iteration. from each line you get the values and you remember the highest and lowest one per column.

Comment: I mean all you need to do is to split each line into values and remember the max and min for each column. you can do this in one iteration or you first parse the data into a table and then do your statistics on the table data.

Comment: Hi @piglet, I’m afraid that’s the bit I don’t know how to do, I’m drawing a blank on how to interate and compare values at the same time.

Comment: I added an example. didn't test it for typos or such things. but it should give you an idea what to do

Comment: Thanks so much @Piglet, I was looking things like table.sort, max and min - this is an interesting approach it’s always good to learn something more..

Comment: you can use table.sort but then you must put each columns values into a separate table first. also a viable approach

Comment: Hi @Piglet, I finally found time to run your code, but it unfortunately gives me an error `lua: home/pi/shared/testing/high_low_average_calcs.lua:37: '<name>' expected near '['` which refers to this specific line `colExtrema.[#row.data].max = math.max(val, oldMax)` Any ideas ?

Comment: typo, remove the `.` after colExtrema

Comment: Wow @Piglet, that was super quick ! :-) - It runs now but returns this message `lua: home/pi/shared/testing/high_low_average_calcs.lua:31: attempt to index local 'dataStr' (a nil value)` - which points to this line `local timeStamp, id, dataStr = line:match("([^,]+),(%d+),(.*)")` . Could this be due to the first row being the column names ? From the second line onwards it’s shows the values ? FYI -  I can have anything from 1 to 8 `field` value columns e.g `created_at,entry_id,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8`

Comment: yeah if you have labels you need to skip the first line of course.

Comment: Hi @Piglet, I’m really struggling with this - if you are still able to help I’d appreciate it. I can’t skip the first line, `local first = true for line in csvFile:lines() do  if first then ... ? ` and that’s where I’m stuck :( . Also can I just check will (can) your code give me the highest, lowest etc in each `fieldx` column of the csv being imported ? Many thanks

Comment: just check wether dataStr is not nil befor you parse the data...  please understand that this is not a coding service. the fact that you fail to solve a simple problem like this suggests that you're not really thinking about it. take pen and paper and draw a flow chart or at least formulate the program in your native language befor you translate that into Lua. I'm sure if I would give you a paper list and a pen you would be able to find the minimum or skip the first line with ease. so what stops you from doing it in Lua?

Comment: how would you skip the first line if you had a paper list?  you would think to yourself: I can read this line, because it is not the first line. or you would think: this line does not contain data, but labels so I skip it. that's exactly what you'd do in Lua. if dataStr is nil there is no data in that line. at least no data of the expected format. so put the processing of dataStr into a conditional statement. isn't that obvious?

Comment: Thanks @Piglet, I only know the Lua language and I’m still learning that, so I have nothing else to refer to. But I’ll keep trying. I appreciate the quick response..

Comment: I mean English, Spanish or whatever your speak perfeclty, not another programming language. If you'd think in C++, you wouldn't aks here

Comment: :-) oh I see, ok, right well with paper and pen in hand , my logic says, if it’s not a match (nil) then I need to skip over it. So `if dataStr == nil  then ` avoid it and move on to the next line - so I added a  `break end` in, but that just seemed to stop it, so I decided to change it around to `~=` which allowed it to progress, but after only 2 lines it returned an error on `62: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)` which relates to this line `local oldMax = colExtrema[#row.data].max or -math.huge` ?

Comment: if you don't know that break terminates a loop this is completely pointless. get your basics right. change it to `colExtrema.max[#row.data]`. I haven't tested this code, it was just to give you an idea.  it should be obvious that colExtrem only has 2 fields. min and max. you should be able to debug this on your own. if you see how a table is construction you know what's inside and what can be indexed.

Comment: Thanks @Piglet, that was it.. it works now. As for the `break’ out of the loop, I thought I knew that, I expected to move onto the next line but it didn’t.  Thanks for your patience (sorry for the frustration) I’m getting better honest :-)